# GUI is freezing while Thread Class background function is running

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

Despite I am using Thread class in my long-term function, my GUI is freezing in PyQt5 and I couldn't solve the problem.
I am using separate py files in this process.

**welding.py**
`

```
python
from threading import Threading

class Weld:
    def __init__(self):
        self.power_supply = PowerSupply()
        self.ui_object = ui_object
    
    # Some code
    
    run_cycle_threader = Thread(target = self.power_supply_run_cycle,
                            args = (self.ui_object,..some args..,self.simulation_mode,))
    run_cycle_threader.start()
    
    #some code
```

`

And at the other module like following:

**power_supply.py**

```py
class PowerSupply:
    def run_cycle(ui, someargs...,simulation_mode):
        #some code interacting with physical device
        #some code which changes GUI elements like Labels, ProgressBars and button colors
```

At other Threading objects I don't face with a problem but this function freezing GUI (for example prevents hovering of buttons)
I have tried to use QTimer class but I got same result.

My complete code is here:
https://github.com/emreisler/weld-redesign

Comment: You know about the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), right? In any case, changing GUI elements directly from a background thread is hairy.

Comment: please provide a [mre]